# Updating spreadsheet with API Key

Tags: api, spreadsheet

I need to update a spreadsheet cell but via API Key instead of OAUTH but even using the Google API explorer, the result is 401 - "Request is missing required authentication credential..." It's possible to assign access right to the spreadsheet so that I can keep using API KEY? Or it's definitively impossible to update via API KEY?

Comment: API key can be used for only GET method. So unfortunately, the API key cannot be used for putting the values to the Spreadsheet, because in this case, POST and PATCH methods are used. If you want to put the values to Spreadsheet without OAuth2 process, how about using the service account and/or Web Apps? If this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: I have a similar issue. If we cannot use API Key, and I don't want to use Token (because it expires, right?). How could I use service account to achieve a simple cell modification in a Google Spreadsheet? Thanks!